# Adjust size of horizontal Scrollview to match size of different lists

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile-development

I have an iOS app, where I have 2 lists that I am displaying on the screen, basically a vertical scrollview, inside of it a horizontal scrollview with 2 lists:

Vertical ScrollView:

- Top Header View
- Horizontal ScrollView:

  1. SampleProfileView
  2. SampleProfileViewB

=============== Top Header View:

```
VStack(alignment: .center){
    VStack(alignment: .center){
        Image(systemName: "star.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .clipShape(.circle)
        
        Text("Some Guy")
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }.padding(.vertical)
}
```

=============== Horizontal ScrollView:

Component 1:

```
@ViewBuilder
func SampleProfileView() -> some View{
    var arrayData: [Int] = Array(1…10);
    LazyVStack{
        Text("About”)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(.horizontal)
             
             VStack{
            ForEach(arrayData, id: \.self){item in
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(color.gradient)
                    //                        .frame(height: 100)
                    
                    Text("\(item)")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Component 2:

```
@ViewBuilder
func SampleProfileViewB() -> some View{
    var arrayData: [Int] = Array(1…50);
    LazyVStack{
        Text("About")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        VStack{
            ForEach(arrayData, id: \.self){item in
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(color.gradient)
                    //                        .frame(height: 100)
                    
                    Text("\(item)")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

=============== Main View Component
I am using both components in the following Main View component:

```
NavigationStack{
    ScrollView(.vertical){
        LazyVStack{
            TopHeaderView()

            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                LazyHStack{
                    
                    SampleProfileView()
                        .id(0)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    
                    
                    SampleProfileViewB()
                        .id(1)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.visible)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

**My Question:**

My question is, how can I have the frame’s height adjust to the size of the different list sizes in `SampleProfileView()` and `SampleProfileViewB()`

As you can see in the picture some of the elements in the scrollview list are hidden, and I am not able to scroll.

As you can see in the following screenshot, it does not reach the end of the list, it's supposed to go all the way to **50th element**, it's only reaching **40th**.

**Screenshot:**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0x2B.png)

Comment: Is this a symptom of using lazy stacks? Try changing all the ```LazyVStack``` to ```VStack``` and the ```LazyHStack``` to ```HStack```.

Comment: The code you provided works just fine on my end. Please provide the Simulator and iOS version so we could better help

Comment: @PierreJanineh Please see attached screenshot. It does not reach the end of the list, reaching only 40 instead of the end of the list at 50th element.

Comment: @BenzyNeez Please see attached screenshot. It does not reach the end of the list, reaching only 40 instead of the end of the list at 50th element.

Comment: @abc on my end it shows correctly..

Comment: @PierreJanineh When I populate the array elements with 10 elements in SampleProfileView and populate SampleProfileViewB with 50 elements, that's when the problem occurs. I have updated the array in question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question.
The problem turned out to be that because I was using a **LazyHStack**.
Once I switched to HStack inside of the **ScrollView(.horizontal)**, it was fixed and all elements are now shown.